# Delphi - A fixed __llmulo (system.pas) procedure or a similar function which implements Int64 multiplication with overflow checking

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Building on question: ["Delphi - Detect Int64 Overflow Error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11344263/delphi-detect-int64-overflow-error).

Does anybody have (or a link to) a __llmulo procedure (system.pas) which correctly implements Int64 multiplication with the **correct overflow checking**? Or maybe a procedure that does something similar.

I have found http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=34049 but it seems (from the comments in the page) that it has bugs.

(I'm using Delphi 7)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).